# Error Adding a video in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying play a Video in the background. My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: VideoSplashViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "m4a")


        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path!)



        self.videoFrame = view.frame
        self.fillMode = .ResizeAspectFill
        self.alwaysRepeat = true
        self.sound = true
        self.startTime = 12.0
        self.duration = 4.0
        self.alpha = 0.7
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.content
```

URL = url

The error I get is :

> Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use
>   '!' or '?'?

Answer (score -1):

I see your code should works. But just in case `Optional type` is you are sure its not nil then add "`!`" on the end to unwrap or use "`?`". For question like this should search first, it's too basic.

Comment: Is it an answer or a comment?